# Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy for Applet

Tags: java, security, applet, jnlp

I need to generate the following key:
PBEKeySpec keyspec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 384);

Locally I can download and use this package to fix the issue:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html

Is there a way to do this for applet? I tried to load required files using JNLP but received the following exception:
"Unable to load resource local_policy.jar"

Could somebody please help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found very usefull post by myself here:
http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html
At the following question there:
Q: How can I use Web Start and JCE together?

The solution of Agnes Juhasz with "UnlimitedCryptoPolicyInstaller" source code worked only (for me).